# Javascript DOM best practice

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, indexing

```
 if (index === 0) {
      const image = document.createElement('img');
      image.alt = 'image';
      image.src = 'https://media.s-bom.com';
      image.width = '100';
      li.appendChild(image);
    }
    if (index === 1) {
      const image = document.createElement('img');
      image.alt = 'image';
      image.src =
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com';
      image.width = '100';
      li.appendChild(image);
    }
    if (index === 2) {
      const image = document.createElement('img');
      image.alt = 'image';
      image.src =
        'https://upload.wikimedia.orgmmer.jpg/220px-The_pragmatic_programmer.jpg';
      image.width = '100';
      li.appendChild(image);
    }
```

Hey, I have this code above in if condition and  I want it to be more clear and not repeated, so anyone have idea how to be more clean.

Comment: Since only difference seems to be the `src` only put that inside the `if()`. No need to duplicate the rest of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing that sets the images apart is the path to the image, I would add all those to an array, and just look them up using the index.

```js
let imageSources = ['https://media.s-bom.com', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com', 'https://upload.wikimedia.orgmmer.jpg/220px-The_pragmatic_programmer.jpg'];

const image = document.createElement('img');
image.alt = 'image';
image.src = imageSources[index];
image.width = '100';
li.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: note that this behaves differently from the OP's code if passed `index=999`